# Time-sensitive in-app purchase on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

With apple's in-app purchase approval system, is it not possible to have new in-app purchase content available every day? I've read in various places that the process typically takes 1-2 days .. sometimes longer. I know the typical answer to this would be to create a back log, but we're working with time-sensitive content and need it to be delivered every day (think newspaper-esk). What's the next best solution other than back logging?

Any ideas?

Comment: I should also mention that once the day has passed, the "old" in-app purchase is still available in the app for sale.

Comment: A subscription model might be more appropriate then.

Comment: With a subscription model will there still be a lag because of approval times?

Comment: No because you sell the subscription, not the individual items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several years later ...

A good way to do this is to submit several in app app purchase items ahead of time via iTunesConnect. I recommend you submit these IAPs at the time of your app submission. If you have any IAPs waiting for review at the time your app is being reviewed, they will also get reviewed at the time.

Comment: So if you submit several IAP items ahead of time, does Apple review them based on the screenshot alone? Or do you actually have to provide the (time-sensitive and possibly not yet existing) content?

Answer (score 2):

Use the same in-app purchase identifier for rotating consumables.

It might be against Apple's policies, though it's highly unlikely that your app will be reviewed regularly after it's approved. I recommend checking the developer agreement before you move ahead with this.